# The best way to change right part of each list of rules element?

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm still trying to learn Wolfram Language but can't understand one thing. Given a list of rules

```
a = {Subscript[A, 1] -> 1, Subscript[A, 2] -> 2, 
  Subscript[A, 3] -> 3, Subscript[A, 4] -> 4}
```

. I need to add a random value to the right side of each rule `RandomReal[{0.0001, 0.0009}]`. What is the best way to do this action?

Comment: a /. {HoldPattern[Rule[x_, y_]] :> 
   Rule[x, y + RandomReal[{0.0001, 0.0009}]]}

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Since you are learning then you might be interested in how natural it is to do that with associations: `a // Association // Map[(# + RandomReal[]) &] // Normal`. The `Normal` at the end is used to convert the association to a list of rules but if you decided to only use associations then you would only have to use `Map[(# + RandomReal[]) &]`

Comment: If you want to use `Map` directly : `(#[[1]] -> (#[[2]] + RandomReal[]) &) /@ a`

Answer (score 6):

Here are a couple of ways:

```
SubsetMap[RandomReal[{0.0001, 0.0009}] + # &, a, {All, 2}]
(* this will add the same random value to each *)

MapAt[RandomReal[{0.0001, 0.0009}] + # &, a, {All, 2}]
(* this will add a different random value to each *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to read more about these list operations...

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
a[[All, 2]] += RandomReal[{0.0001, 0.0009}, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread[Keys@a -> Values@a + RandomReal[{0.0001, 0.0009}, Length@a]]
```

> ```
> {Subscript[A, 1] -> 1.00013, Subscript[A, 2] -> 2.00031, 
>  Subscript[A, 3] -> 3.00027, Subscript[A, 4] -> 4.00038}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[0];

list = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4};
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[x_ :> x + RandomReal[{0.1, 0.9}], {All, 2}] @ list
```

> {a -> 1.62197, b -> 2.60646, c -> 3.64625, d -> 4.55308}

Converting `list` to an `Association` will add the same random value
to each element:

```
<|list|> + RandomReal[{0.1, 0.9}]
```

> <|a -> 1.88095, b -> 2.88095, c -> 3.88095, d -> 4.88095|>

Back to list of rules:

```
Normal[%]
```

> {a -> 1.88095, b -> 2.88095, c -> 3.88095, d -> 4.88095}

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[0];

list = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `ReplaceAll`:

```
list /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[a, b + RandomReal[{0.1, 0.9}]]
```

> `{a -> 1.32593, b -> 2.33718, c -> 3.65676, d -> 4.51128}`